# Setup vite --template react and eslint (airbnb)

Tags: reactjs, eslint, vite, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to configure a project using vite.js and airbnb eslint setup.
I would like a "create-react-app"-kind of workflow where the linting is made every time the server starts/restarts, but I'm having a lot of trouble in doing so. To make things work I followed this video in particular: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSl12yjFgDo. They use @rollup/plugin-eslint to achieve linting on every server restart, with the option `{ enforce: "pre" }`, but it's absolutely not working for me. I have 200+ linting errors from files internal to vite.
This is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import eslint from '@rollup/plugin-eslint';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), { ...eslint(), enforce: 'pre' }],
});
```

This my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb/hooks'],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [],
  rules: {},
};
```

As you can see it's all very minimal at the moment.
Can you please point me towards the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using `vite-plugin-eslint` plugin to run eslint on vite server restart.
Here a example config which is working fine here on a `vite react ts` project.

*vite.config.ts*

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import reactRefresh from '@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh';
import eslint from 'vite-plugin-eslint';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [eslint(), reactRefresh()],
});
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "vitetest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "serve": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "^1.3.6",
    "react": "^17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "vite-plugin-eslint": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.10.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.2",
    "vite": "^2.6.4"
  }
}
```

*.eslintrc.json*

```
{
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2021,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:react/recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"    ],
      "rules": {
        // suppress errors for missing 'import React' in files
       "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
       "semi": [2, "always"]
      }
  }
```

Comment: Do you have an example for a js setup?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to move eslint plugin before react plugin in vite.config.js